# what should be the optimum value of max_schema_agreement_wait in cassandra, by default it is 10

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

what should be the optimum  value of `max_schema_agreement_wait` in cassandra cluster, by default it is 10. Most of the time I'm getting this error while schema creation:

`"2019-07-29 21:26:32,003 ERROR {"timestamp": "2019-07-29T21:26:32.003571+00:00", "app": "submarine", "msg_id": "5", "namespace": "logger.srs.main", "trace_id": "34bed792-2f7c-409c-a9ba-f30b3f43c12a", "priority": 3, "host": "7bb5f82d1961", "msg": "\"OperationTimedOut to execute query: errors={'172.16.0.28': 'Request timed out while waiting for schema agreement. See Session.execute[_async](timeout) and Cluster.max_schema_agreement_wait.'}, last_host=172.16.1.26".`

Should i increase the value to a larger value??
What will be the reprecussions of that??

PS: I have a 3 node cassandra cluster

Comment: what is the precise version of Cassandra?

Comment: Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: that's really strange - 10 seconds should be enough for 3-nodes cluster. do you see anything in the `system.log` on the servers?

Comment: are there any down nodes?

Comment: yes , sometime i can see one of the nodes go down during the process, does that changes anything???